# Use Terraform to Manage Azure DevOps Teams, Groups, and Users originating from Active Directory

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am attempting to create a generic configuration variable in Terraform that will allow someone to setup a new repo in Azure DevOps and specify the users or groups that should be assigned to each group or team.

All groups and members come from and are managed by Azure Active directory.

**There are two things I am trying to achieve:**

1. Assign AD users and AD groups to the existing built-in Azure DevOps default groups that exist today like (`Readers` and `Contributors`) and
2. Create custom team names and assign AD users and groups to them.

How might someone go about defining that structure in Terraform?

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? Any errors?

Comment: It's incomplete. I need to figure out how to dynamically loop through and create the TF resources based on those map structures. That code is far from the structure I need to achieve it. Plus looking up AD groups is different from looking up entitlements for individual users.

Comment: You are already iterating over them, e.g. `for_each = var.TF_VAR_ado_groups`. So what's wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out after much trial and error. Assume you want to create or update the following Azure DevOps groups or teams and have a variable called `permissions` like this:

```
locals {
    permissions = {
    # Azure DevOps Default Groups
    "Project Administrators": {
      ad_groups = [
        "ActiveDirectoryGroup1",
        "ActiveDirectoryGroup2"
      ]
      ado_groups = [
        "AzureDevOpsGroup1",
        "AzureDevOpsGroup2"
      ],
      users = [
        "user1@example.com",
        "user2@example.com"
      ]
    },
    "Contributors": {
      ad_groups = [
        "ActiveDirectoryGroup3"
      ]
      ado_groups = [
        "My New Team"
      ],
      users = []
    },
    # Azure DevOps Create New Group
    "My New DevOps Group": {
      custom_group = true
      ad_groups = [
        "ActiveDirectoryGroup4"
      ]
      ado_groups = [],
      users = []
    },
    # Create Azure DevOps Teams
    "My New Team": {
      is_team = true,
      team_admins = [
        "user1@example.com"
      ],
      ad_groups = [
        "ActiveDirectoryGroup5"
      ],
      ado_groups = [],
      users = [
        "user1@example.com",
        "user2@example.com",
        "user3@example.com",
        "user4@example.com",
        "user5@example.com",
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can use the following terraform code to parse that `permissions` variable to and create/update groups as well as create teams dynamically:

```
// ROLE / PERMISSION ASSIGNMENTS

# Aggregate each resource by it's category into a single list
locals {
  ad_groups = toset(flatten([for entry in local.permissions : entry.ad_groups]))
  ado_groups = toset(flatten([for entry in local.permissions : entry.ado_groups]))
  users = toset(flatten([for entry in local.permissions : entry.users]))
}

# Create entitlements for all users
resource "azuredevops_user_entitlement" "users" {
  for_each              = local.users
  principal_name        = each.key
  account_license_type  = "basic"
}

# Get all users
data "azuredevops_users" "all" {
  for_each          = local.users
  principal_name    = each.key
}

# Get active directory descriptors roster
data "azuread_group" "aad" {
  for_each          = local.ad_groups
  display_name      = each.key
  security_enabled  = true
}
resource "azuredevops_group" "aad_groups" {
  for_each          = toset(values(data.azuread_group.aad)[*].object_id)
  origin_id         = each.key
}

# Create new groups
resource "azuredevops_group" "new" {
  for_each     = {for group_name, entry in local.permissions : group_name => entry if !lookup(entry, "is_team", false) && lookup(entry, "custom_group", false)}
  scope        = azuredevops_project.example.id
  display_name = each.key
  description  = "Managed by Terraform"
}

# Query for all groups including the ones we just created
data "azuredevops_groups" "all" {
  project_id = azuredevops_project.example.id
}

# Create descriptor map to make lookups easy
locals {
  descriptor_map = merge(
    {for entry in flatten(values(data.azuredevops_users.all)[*].users[*]) : entry.principal_name => entry.descriptor},
    {for entry in data.azuredevops_groups.all.groups : entry.display_name => entry.descriptor},
    {for entry in azuredevops_group.aad_groups : entry.display_name => entry.descriptor},
    {for entry in azuredevops_group.new : entry.display_name => entry.descriptor}
  )
}

# Create or update teams
resource "azuredevops_team" "teams" {
  for_each    = {for team_name, entry in local.permissions : team_name => entry if lookup(entry, "is_team", false)}
  project_id  = azuredevops_project.example.id
  name        = each.key
  description = "Managed by Terraform"
  administrators = toset(compact(concat([for user in each.value.team_admins : lookup(local.descriptor_map, user, "")])))
  members = toset(compact(concat(
    [for user in each.value.users : lookup(local.descriptor_map, user, "")],
    [for group in each.value.ad_groups : lookup(local.descriptor_map, group, "")],
    [for group in each.value.ado_groups : lookup(local.descriptor_map, group, "")]
  )))
}

locals {
  descriptor_map2 = merge(
    local.descriptor_map,
    {for team_name, entry in azuredevops_team.teams : team_name => entry.descriptor}
  )
}

# Update group memberships
resource "azuredevops_group_membership" "assignments" {
  for_each     = {for group_name, entry in local.permissions : group_name => entry if !lookup(entry, "is_team", false)}
  group = local.descriptor_map2[each.key]
  mode = "overwrite"
  members = toset(compact(concat(
    [for user in each.value.users : lookup(local.descriptor_map2, user, "")],
    [for group in each.value.ad_groups : lookup(local.descriptor_map2, group, "")],
    [for group in each.value.ado_groups : lookup(local.descriptor_map2, group, "")]
  )))
}
```

### Permission Entry Fields

The following fields are defined and available for each entry within the `permissions` map:

The **map key** represents the name of the group or team you are creating or updating. The **map value** for a given key can contain the following options:

- **`is_team`** - Required to be set to `true` when creating a team. Defaults to false.
- **`team_admins`** - (optional) Used to set the admins of a team.
- **`custom_group`** - (optional) Used to set to `true` when creating a *new* group. This flag helps Terraform discern between existing built-in groups like Contributors/Readers/etc. and custom ones you create. Defaults to false.
- **`ad_groups`** - (required) An array of Active Directory groups that should be assigned as members. These values are case sensitive. Pass an empty array if no membership assignments.
- **`ado_groups`** - (required) An array of Azure DevOps groups that should be assigned as members. These values are case sensitive. Pass an empty array if no membership assignments.
- **`users`** - (required) An array of email addresses. If a valid descriptor is not found for the email address in Active Directory, then this user cannot be associated to the group or team. Pass an empty array if no membership assignments.

### Known Limitations

- The default team Azure DevOps creates when a new project is created (usually denoted by a team name of "<PROJECT_NAME> Team") is unused and currently unable to be managed in Terraform.