# Use Terraform to Create Azure DevOps Approval Checks for Environments

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-devops-rest-api

Terraform does not yet support creating approval checks for Azure DevOps environments today. What is the best approach to create Azure DevOps environment approvals using Terraform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Terraform doesn't support creating environment approvals today, we have to do it manually with the Azure DevOps REST API.

This is a perfect scenario for using a [`local-exec` provisioner](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec). Although the docs warn against it, this is a good use case for it since the following holds true from the docs:

> By default, provisioners run when the resource they are defined within
> is created. Creation-time provisioners are only run during creation,
> not during updating or any other lifecycle. They are meant as a means
> to perform bootstrapping of a system.
>
> If a creation-time provisioner fails, the resource is marked as
> tainted. A tainted resource will be planned for destruction and
> recreation upon the next terraform apply. Terraform does this because
> a failed provisioner can leave a resource in a semi-configured state.
> Because Terraform cannot reason about what the provisioner does, the
> only way to ensure proper creation of a resource is to recreate it.
> This is tainting.

So assume we have this variable configuration in our variables:

```
TF_VAR_ado_environments = {
    "dev": { 
        approvers = ["Contributors", "user1@example.com"]
    }, 
    "test": { 
        approvers = ["Contributors"]
    }
}
```

Then we need to do lookups of the IDs of the approvers. These IDs are GUIDs in Azure DevOps. So we create a map variable called `identity_map` where the key is the group name/team name/user email and the value is the ID of the entity. You may have to do several lookups like I did below and then merged them together into one map for easy lookups later. See [this question I answered about setting up Azure DevOps permissions using Terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75153328/use-terraform-to-manage-azure-devops-teams-groups-and-users-originating-from-a) to see where the rest of this stuff came from if you need more ideas around it:

```
locals {
  identity_map = merge(
    {for entry in flatten(values(data.azuredevops_users.all)[*].users[*]) : entry.principal_name => entry.id},
    {for entry in data.azuredevops_groups.all.groups : entry.display_name => entry.origin_id},
    {for entry in azuredevops_group.aad_groups : entry.display_name => entry.id},
    {for entry in azuredevops_group.new : entry.display_name => entry.id},
    {for team_name, entry in azuredevops_team.teams : team_name => entry.id}
  )
}
```

Then you can create the Azure DevOps environments using Terraform along with a provisioner command that that calls curl to do the approval creation after each environment gets created. Note that the provisioner only runs when the environment is created. So if approvals are manually added or removed in the GUI, TF will not detect it. This is still a best effort at doing the initial setup though. Just swap out the values in the variables below with your environment specific values:

```
resource "azuredevops_environment" "env" {
  for_each     = toset(keys(var.TF_VAR_ado_environments))
  project_id   = azuredevops_project.example.id
  name         = each.key
  description = "Managed by Terraform"

  # Create Environment Approval
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<COMMAND
curl -X POST https://dev.azure.com/${var.TF_VAR_org_name}/${var.TF_VAR_project_name}/_apis/pipelines/checks/configurations?api-version=7.1-preview.1 -H "Authorization: Basic ${base64encode(format("%s:%s", "myaccount@example.com", var.TF_VAR_PAT))}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @- <<DATA
{
       "settings": {
         "approvers": ${jsonencode([for approver in var.TF_VAR_ado_environments[each.key].approvers : {"id": lookup(local.identity_map, approver, "")}])},
         "executionOrder": "anyOrder",
         "minRequiredApprovers": 1
       },
       "timeout": 43200,
       "type": {
         "id": "8c6f20a7-a545-4486-9777-f762fafe0d4d",
         "name": "Approval"
       },
       "resource": {
         "type": "environment",
         "id": "${self.id}"
       }
     }
DATA
    COMMAND
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from version 0.6 of the azuredevops terraform provider it supports the resource `azuredevops_check_approval`. Example:

```
resource "azuredevops_project" "example" {
  name = "Example Project"
}

resource "azuredevops_environment" "example" {
  project_id = azuredevops_project.example.id
  name       = "Example Environment"
}

resource "azuredevops_group" "example" {
  display_name = "some-azdo-group"
}

resource "azuredevops_check_approval" "example" {
  project_id           = azuredevops_project.example.id
  target_resource_id   = azuredevops_environment.example.id
  target_resource_type = "environment"

  requester_can_approve = true
  approvers = [
    azuredevops_group.example.origin_id,
  ]
}
```

Reference: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/microsoft/azuredevops/latest/docs/resources/check_approval